# Version conflicts of PyTorch model on Jetson Nano

Tags: python, pytorch, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have a PyTorch model I have trained on a server that has PyTorch 2.0.0 installed on Python 3.8. Now I need to deploy that model on a Jetson Nano Developer Kit which has following configurations:

```
NVIDIA Jetson Nano Developer Kit
JetPack: 4.6.2
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Kernel Version: 4.9.253-tegra
CUDA: 10.2.300
CUDNN: 8.2.1.32
TensorRT: 8.2.1.8
Vision Works: 1.6.0.501
VPI: 1.2.3
Vulcan: 1.2.70
```

It already has `Pytorch 1.10.2` installed on it.

I use the following code to load the model using the trained weights.

```py
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FastRCNNPredictor

NUM_CLASSES = 2
CLASSES = ['__background__', 'license-plate']
DEVICE = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
OUT_DIR = ''
WEIGHTS_PATH = 'best_model.pth'

def create_model(num_classes, pretrained=True):
    # Load Faster RCNN pre-trained model
    model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn()
    
    # Get the number of input features 
    in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
    # define a new head for the detector with required number of classes
    model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes) 

    return model

def main():
    checkpoint = torch.load(WEIGHTS_PATH, map_location=DEVICE)
    model = create_model(num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, coco_model=False)
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
    model.to(DEVICE).eval()
    model_scripted = torch.jit.script(model)
    model_scripted.save('model_scripted.pt')

main()
```

When the script is run, the following error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jetson_inference.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "jetson_inference.py", line 29, in main
    model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
  File "/home/vha/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1483, in load_state_dict
    self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for FasterRCNN:
    Missing key(s) in state_dict: "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.0.weight", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.0.bias", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.1.weight", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.1.bias", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.2.weight", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.2.bias", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.3.weight", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.3.bias", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.0.weight", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.0.bias", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.1.weight", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.1.bias", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.2.weight", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.2.bias", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.3.weight", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.3.bias", "rpn.head.conv.weight", "rpn.head.conv.bias". 
    Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.0.0.weight", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.0.0.bias", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.1.0.weight", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.1.0.bias", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.2.0.weight", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.2.0.bias", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.3.0.weight", "backbone.fpn.inner_blocks.3.0.bias", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.0.0.weight", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.0.0.bias", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.1.0.weight", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.1.0.bias", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.2.0.weight", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.2.0.bias", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.3.0.weight", "backbone.fpn.layer_blocks.3.0.bias", "rpn.head.conv.0.0.weight", "rpn.head.conv.0.0.bias".
```

This is my first time working with a Jetson device and I'd appreciate any help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're experimenting with ML-Models. I strongly advise to use python virtual environments. This way you might avoid version conflicts. [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) would be the simplest. Alternatives would be [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) or [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: I tried conda environments with different python versions as well, but I'm limited to Python (3.6 or lower) since the Jetson Nano has JetPack 4.6. Hence I can't install PyTorch 1.11.0 or newer.